# Angular2 How to fix error for drag and drop

Tags: angularjs

I build soure code from: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula

But i got error: `window['dragula'] is not defined.`

Please help me build example above or fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking questions on SOF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to load these js/css files:

```
"node_modules/ng2-dragula/node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.js",
"node_modules/ng2-dragula/node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css",
```